# singular event - may I use these words in referring to an upcoming 50 year high school reunion?

Tags: word-choice

I'm inviting classmates to attend a Fifty Year High School class reunion.  May I appropriately call it a "singular event?"

Answer (score 2):

*Singular* has two meanings -- exceptionally good or unique. Since you're encouraging your classmates to come to this social function, you obviously can't tell the truth -- that it will be a depressing grotesquery attended by people who couldn't stand each other five decades ago. Your meaning is clear, the usage is appropriate in theory, and anyway, no one will be fooled.

It's also appropriate to ascribe uniqueness to the "celebration". After all, there won't be another fiftieth reunion, and after that gathering it's unlikely there will be another like get together.